# How I get params of url in python

Tags: python

I need get params of url in Python:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server, demo_app

def showresult(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK' # HTTP Status
    headers = [('Content-type', 'application/json')] # HTTP Headers
    start_response(status, headers)

    # The returned object is going to be printed
    return "ok"

httpd = make_server('', 8081, showresult)

# Respond to requests until process is killed
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The code it execute ok when I access http://localhost:8081

I need, when I access to "http://localhost:8081/?cid=5&aid=4" 
get cid and aid value

Comment: Take a look at [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/davidbgk/1311056)

Comment: I think its `parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])`. `parse_qs` can be found in several modules and its moved around a bit between python 2 and 3, but its in the `cgi` module in both versions.

Comment: The method [`cgi.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_qs) is deprecated, instead use [`urlparse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs)

Comment: @MauroBaraldi `urlparse` doesn't exist in python 3. Its `urllib.parse.parse_qs`.

Comment: You're right @tdelaney. My bad! Thanks for hot fix :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to achieve that, is to use [`urlparse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs)

```
from urlparse import parse_qs
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server, demo_app

def showresult(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK' # HTTP Status
    headers = [('Content-type', 'application/json')] # HTTP Headers
    start_response(status, headers)
    params = parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])  #  Here you get the values in a dict!
    print params

    # The returned object is going to be printed
    return "ok"

httpd = make_server('', 8081, showresult)

# Respond to requests until process is killed
httpd.serve_forever()
```